# How big are original LEGO bricks?

Tags: history, vintage

How big are/were the original LEGO bricks? What about those sold in Canada from 1970 to 1985/1990?

Comment: The same size as current ones? You can use bricks from the 1960s with current ones without issues. Are you thinking of something specific which isn't compatible?

Comment: Early LEGO bricks had grooves in the sides for windows to slide down, but they patented the exact size of the bricks so that should still be the same.